# How do I make a 3rd party livehelp autofill with Joomla users' names and email when logged in?

Tags: php, user

I'm trying to get a 3rd party livehelp to autofill with Joomla users name and email when logged in.

This is the js code to autofill:

```
LHCChatOptionsPage.attr_prefill = new Array();
LHCChatOptionsPage.attr_prefill.push({'name':'email','value':'test@email.com','hidden':true});
LHCChatOptionsPage.attr_prefill.push({'name':'username','value':'Username here'});
```

And this is the php code to get the variables from Joomla:

```
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
$user_name = $user->name; 
$user_email = $user->email;
```

But what do I need to do to use them together?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [addScriptDeclaration](https://docs.joomla.org/JDocument/addScriptDeclaration) for this. With this function you can add JavaScript code to the `<head>` of your website.

```
<?php
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$user = JFactory::getUser();

$js = "LHCChatOptionsPage.attr_prefill = new Array();";
$js .= "LHCChatOptionsPage.attr_prefill.push({'name': 'email', 'value': '" . $user->email . "', 'hidden': true});";
$js .= "LHCChatOptionsPage.attr_prefill.push({'name': 'username', 'value': '" . $user->name . "'});"

$doc->addScriptDeclaration($js);
```

Comment: Hi and thanks!
So as you say, this will add it to the <head> of the page
But for this to work, I need the js code (prefill) to be with the rest of the js code that calls the livehelp.
Many thanks if anyone can help?